# Ansible ping fails for user that cannot write to /var/folders, even when sudo is enabled

Tags: ansible

The Ansible ping command is failing.  How can I fix it?

## Here is the inventory file:

```
172.18.192.60 ansible_ssh_user=access ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/.ssh/ec2/access.pem
```

If I try to run the Ansible `ping` module against the host without `--sudo`, I cannot do so.  That makes sense because the remote user doesn't have write access to `/var/folders/`, which is apparently where Ansible is storing some interim data.  But even if I use sudo, I get the same behavior.

```
$ ansible --version
ansible 1.6.10 (release1.6.10 8959338284) last updated 2014/08/04 16:21:41 (GMT -400)

$ ansible all -i deploy/develop_hosts -m ping -vvvv --sudo --sudo-user=root
<172.18.192.60> ESTABLISH CONNECTION FOR USER: access
<172.18.192.60> REMOTE_MODULE ping
<172.18.192.60> EXEC ['ssh', '-C', '-tt', '-vvv', '-o', 'ControlMaster=auto', '-o', 'ControlPersist=60s', '-o', 'ControlPath=/Users/scartwright/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r', '-o', 'IdentityFile=/Users/scartwright/.ssh/ec2/access.pem', '-o', 'KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no', '-o', 'PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey', '-o', 'PasswordAuthentication=no', '-o', 'User=access', '-o', 'ConnectTimeout=10', '172.18.192.60', "/bin/sh -c 'mkdir -p $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1407257059.86-51557039753935 && chmod a+rx $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1407257059.86-51557039753935 && echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1407257059.86-51557039753935'"]
<172.18.192.60> PUT /var/folders/9x/ctr6mk5x787g9nqk4r92sgg00000gn/T/tmpjvL2TY TO /home/access/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1407257059.86-51557039753935/ping
172.18.192.60 | FAILED => failed to transfer file to /home/access/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1407257059.86-51557039753935/ping:

Connection closed
```

## The referenced file doesn't exist on the remote host:

```
access@ip-172-18-192-60:~$ ls -la /var/folders
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Aug  5 17:14 .
drwxr-xr-x 12 root root 4096 Aug  5 15:46 ..

access@ip-172-18-192-60:~$ sudo su

root@ip-172-18-192-60:/home/access# ls -la /var/folders
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Aug  5 17:14 .
drwxr-xr-x 12 root root 4096 Aug  5 15:46 ..
root@ip-172-18-192-60:/home/access#
```

## Here is a list of things that hasn't helped:

- Putting `ansible_sudo=yes` in the hosts file
- Putting the `--user` and `--private-key` on the command line instead of in the hosts file
- Using the FQDN instead of the IP address in the hosts file
- Using `--su` (and `--su-user=root`) instead of `--sudo`
- Explicitly setting the connection mode `-c paramiko` or `-c ssh`

Gathering facts fails in the same way when using `ansible-playbook`.
This problem is not new; it also occurred with Ansible 1.5.4.

## Question:

How can I make my hosts reachable?  Is there a way to tell Ansible to use a different directory other than `/var/folders`, assuming that's the problem?  Is there something else I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 2):

SFTP is not enabled on the remote host, which is why the transfers failed. I created an `ansible.cfg` file with the following contents, and now it works just fine.

```
[ssh_connection]
scp_if_ssh=True
```

For more information, see documentation for the [Ansible Configuration File](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_configuration.html#openssh-specific-settings).

Answer (score 1):

Ansible stores temporary files in the home directory of the user i.e. /home/access/.ansible/ in your case. /var/folders/ is the directory on your local system where you are running Ansible from.

Comment: This was useful because it got me looking at the transfer instead of permissions.  To be clear, `ansible` is not running _from_ that directory, but the file is local.

Comment: I mean, local system where you are running Ansible from. /var/folders is the tmp directory where Ansible stores its temporary files and removes it after execution completes.